# Inserting at the end with C++

Tags: c++, list

I wrote code that can create a Linked List, insert elements into the beginning or end, and then display it.

```
struct ListElem
{
    int        info;
    ListElem * next;
};

// shortcut for list = pointer to a list element
typedef ListElem * List;

// empty list is a Null Pointer
const List emptyList = 0;

void printList(List lst) {
        for (; lst!= 0; lst = lst->next) {
            cout << lst->info << endl;
        }
}
void insertElem(List& lst, int info) {
    ListElem *ptrElem = new ListElem;
    ptrElem->info = info;
    ptrElem->next = lst;
    lst = ptrElem;
}
void insertLast(List& lst, int info) {
    ListElem *ptrElem = new ListElem;
    ptrElem->info = info;
    ptrElem->next = NULL;
    if (lst == emptyList) {
        insertElem(lst, info);
        return;
    }
    else {
        while (lst ->next) {
            lst = lst->next;
        }
        lst->next = ptrElem;
    }
}
```

I tried out the insertLast function on main:

```
int main()
{
    // fill List with values 1 to 10
    List list1 = emptyList;
    for (int value = 1; value <= 10; value++)
    {
        //insertElem( list1, value ); 
        insertLast(list1, value);
    }

    //print list
    printList(list1);  // should provide sequence 1 2 3 ... 10
```

But for some reason printList only shows 9 and 10, instead of 1,2,3,..,10. This problem only happens with insertLast. insertElem seems to work fine.

Comment: You can reproduce this with far fewer than ten elements. Smaller test cases are easier to debug.

Comment: If you want a linked list in C++ (you usually don't, prefer `std::vector`), use `std::list` or `std::forward_list`. Unless this is purely a learning exercise (in which case your question should *say so*), you are wasting your time by re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that inside `insertLast()`, you pass the list argument by reference. That is, each change done to the list will be visible outside the function. On these lines - `while (lst ->next) {lst = lst->next;}`, you change the list reference, so the first node of the list is modified with each add.

The solution would be to take an auxiliary iterator Node, to iterate your list, or pass your List by value, change the list as you do now, and return the modified copy.

Below is the `insertLast()` method, rewritten to iterate the list with an auxiliary node:

```
void insertLast(List& lst, int info) {
    ListElem *ptrElem = new ListElem;
    ListElem *aux = lst;

    ptrElem->info = info;
    ptrElem->next = NULL;
    if (lst == emptyList) {
        insertElem(lst, info);
        return;
    }
    else {
        while (aux ->next) {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        aux->next = ptrElem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this behaviour is that after your function call to the function that insert element at last what happens is that your linked list header starts pointing to the second last element of linked list not first element of linked list.

Solution to this is quite simple in the your function to insert element at last just make a temporary variable put it equal to linked list header and traverse the linked list using this temporary variable and do not modify the linked list header that you are passing as function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you use references very bad
see your insertLast function

```
void insertLast(List& lst, int info) {
    ListElem *ptrElem = new ListElem;
    ptrElem->info = info;
    ptrElem->next = NULL;
    if (lst == emptyList) {
        insertElem(lst, info);
        return;
    }
    else {
        while (lst ->next) {
            lst = lst->next;
        }
        lst->next = ptrElem;
    }
```

you set your lst with last item and lst is reference so in your main function list1 is changed and you have lose you list
try:

```
void insertLast(List& lst, int info) {
    ListElem *ptrElem = new ListElem;
    List* newlst = lst;
    ptrElem->info = info;
    ptrElem->next = NULL;
    if (lst == emptyList) {
        insertElem(lst, info);
        return;
    }
    else {
        while (newlst ->next) {
            newlst = newlst->next;
        }
        newlst->next = ptrElem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- At the start of `insertLast` function you always create new element, regarding that yu use it only if this is not the first element in the list. In this case you will always have a memory leak.
- The second problem that make your code acting strangely, is that you change the head of the list to point to the place before the last place in every insert. What you can do to avoid this is to use `ListElem` pointer, that will point to the head of the list and changes on this one will have no effect on the originally list head pointer.

This function shuld do the work for you:

```
void insertLast(List& lst, int info) {
    if (lst == emptyList) {
        insertElem(lst, info);
        return;
    }
    else {
        ListElem *ptrElem = new ListElem;
        ptrElem->info = info;
        ptrElem->next = NULL;
        ListElem* temp = lst;
        while (temp->next) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = ptrElem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `insertLast` modyfies input lst, so it points to the one before last element at the end of for loop in main. That is why `printList` gives you only last two numbers.

It can be done in one function. You would need another one, if you would like to append element to the front, but that is not your question.

```
void insertElem(List& lst, int info) {
    List elemntToInsert = new ListElem();
    elemntToInsert->info = info;
    elemntToInsert->next = nullptr;

    //Check if input is null list
    if (lst == nullptr)
    {
        lst = elemntToInsert;
    }
    else //Else append at the end
    {
        List lastElement = lst;
        while (lastElement->next != nullptr)
            lastElement = lastElement->next;
        lastElement->next = elemntToInsert;
    }
}
```